# Finding the upper bound of the length of a closed walk

Tags: approximation, traveling-salesman

I am having trouble understanding a part of the proof of [Lemma 2 (Page 184)](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/PDF/KarpSteeleTSPChapter.pdf).

It says the length of the tour is $$ \leq  \lceil n^{1/2} \rceil + \triangle(n + \lceil n^{1/2} \rceil) + \sqrt{2} $$ I don't understand how they came up with this inequality. I can understand where the $\sqrt{2} $ comes from, since we have to travel from the final point to the initial point and that is the length of the diagonal. As for the rest, to me somehow it seems that the inequality should be $$ <(\triangle + 1)(n + \lceil n^{1/2} \rceil) + \sqrt{2}$$, where I have used the triangle inequality.

I am having also a hard time simplifying *my* inequality to something along the lines $c \sqrt{n} $ where $c>0$ whereas the one given in the proof is easier to manipulate.

Comment: Since links rot over time, it's better to transcribe a problem into LaTeX whenever possible, rather than simply posting a link.

Comment: I tried at this for about 45 minutes but couldn't quite get it. Note that there are only $n+\lceil \sqrt n \rceil - 1$ points, and since $\sqrt 2$ already accounts for one of the edges, there are only $n+\lceil \sqrt n \rceil - 2$ edges that need to be accounted for. Besides that I got the same thing you did, $(\Delta + 1)(n+\lceil \sqrt n \rceil - 2) + \sqrt 2$. This is what I would call a badly written proof.

Comment: To add to my earlier comment, in this case it seems that the lemma is sufficiently long that my "whenever possible" wouldn't apply. (At least *I* wouldn't bother transcribing the proof if I were posting the question.)

Comment: Hmm.... I divide the region into squares of size $$ \frac{1}{\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil}  \times \frac{1} {\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil} $$ and then bound the distance between points in those squares by $\frac{ \sqrt{2} }{\lceil n^{1/2} \rceil}$. I get a *different* inequality but it can be manipulated to get $c \sqrt{n}$